# Customise the page editing sub-menu options

Tags: 2007, editing-menu

I'm trying to remove a drop down sub-menu option from the page editing menu in moss 2007.

I'm using the following xml in my customeditingmenu.xml located in the masterpage gallery > Editing Menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Console>
   <structure >   
           <ConsoleNode ConfigMenu="Delete" ChangedNodeID="saCancelApprovalWorkflow"/>
    </structure >
</Console>
```

This should delete the node from navigation but after an IISreset it still appears.

I've confirmed that adding this to the editingmenu.xml file directly works.

Can anyone spot a problem with the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

have you read this stuff?

it's posted by Andrew Conell right after the msdn article

> If you follow these steps explicitly, it won't work.
>
> Under the section To create a custom server control that can change the configuration of >the Quick Access buttons, steps 9-11 say to create the CustomQuickAccess.XML file and >save it with your changes. That implies the file should reside in the same directory as >the QuickAccess.xml file. Using the out-of-the-box Publishing Portal template, that won't >work. This is because an actual CustomQuickAccess.XML file was created when the site was >created within the Editing Menu folder in the Master Page Gallery. This is the file that >the Page Editing Toolbar will examine to add custom buttons. The same applies for the >Page Editing menu (not just the Quick Access buttons).
>
> Therefore, don't save your changes in a new file. Take the changes and apply them to the >CustomQuickAccess.XML file within the Editing Menu in the Master Page Gallery.
>
> The documentation seems to imply this further up on the same page under the Caution note >in the Modify XML Data Source Files section.
>
> -AC, MVP MOSS [www.andrewconnell.com/blog]

src : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa674506.aspx

Comment: You'll see from my post that I am making theses changes to the customeditingmenu.xml file in the master page gallery.